# Audio Randomly Switches from Line Out to Headphones

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, 19.10, 20.04

While using an application that uses sound drivers, (such as watching a video in VLC, YouTube, or in a Discord call:

- Settings window will visibly flicker.
- Output device will quickly switch from Line Out (internal audio card) to USB headphones.
- Input (USB mic) will lose connection.
- Earphones will usually loudly "CRACK" or "POP."

There are a couple variations of behavior I have noticed:

1. If on Line Out, it will switch **to** my USB headphones and stay there.
2. If on my USB headphones, it will switch to Line Out, then **back** to USB headphones.

Frequency of recurrence varies from 0 - "many" times per day.

Quitting the app sometimes ceases this behavior, or sometimes opening a new sound-using app while leaving the affected app. For instance, the problem was happening every few seconds, but after I opened OBS to attempt to screen capture the flickering, the problem stopped.

This problem started last year very soon after first installing Ubuntu 18.04. It has persisted through 19.04, 19.10, and 20.04. I'm on Alsa / PulseAudio, but I do not know if either of these are the culprit.

I have seen several similar issues:

- [Audio switches between headphone and output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294969/audio-switches-between-headphone-and-output)
- [Audio switching internal to headphone for a moment and turning back while playing sound and there is no headphone connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866109/audio-switching-internal-to-headphone-for-a-moment-and-turning-back-while-playin)
- [sound keeps switching from line out to headphones randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129950/sound-keeps-switching-from-line-out-to-headphones-randomly)

**but** none seem to have confirmed causes or solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be a faulty USB DAC, probably due to a short in the cord. The moment I borrowed a friend's DAC, the problem stopped. Not sure if this problem is what the others were experiencing in the threads I mentioned.

The cord had been previously damaged prior to moving to Linux. The problem never occurred in Windows though, so either Windows handled the damaged cord in a way that was never made apparent, or it only affected Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this is to override the headphone jack with the line out jack, I fixed this using hdajackretask.

simply install alsa-tools-gui package:

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui
```

then open it in terminal or in your OS app manager and
choose your audio card. look for green headphone then override it with line out. choose install boot override then reboot